# Trouble with having a variable in getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, css

*What I'm trying to ultimately do:* I'm trying to make a button (think of it like a next button) that cycles through 9 images, each with its own id and link.

*The Problem:* Whenever I call the function that's supposed to switch the id (ex. from youtube to imgur) and change the display from none to block, nothing seems to happen.

*What I've tried:* I first tried a switch statement that looked a little something like this (this is with all of the related javascript functions as well as the html):

**NOTE:** I'm currently only worried about the next button's functionality.

```
<body>
<div id="backnext">
    <button class="button2" id="back"> < </button>
    <button class="button2" id="next" onclick="linkSwitch()"> > </button>
    <div id="tablecontainer">
        <ul id="tablelinks">
            <li> <!--Youtube Link-->
                <a id="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Imgur Link-->
                <a id="imgur" href="https://imgur.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Facebook Link-->
                <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Google Link-->
                <a id="google" href="https://www.google.com/"> </a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Ion Bank Link-->
                <a id="ionbank" href="https://ionbank.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Paypal Link-->
                <a id="paypal" href="https://www.paypal.com/home"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Aol Link-->
                <a id="aol" href="https://mail.aol.com/webmail-std/en-us/suite"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Amazon Link-->
                <a id="amazon" href="http://www.amazon.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Reddit Link-->
                <a id="reddit" href="https://www.reddit.com/"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div>

<script>
var id, arraynum, x;
id = ["youtube", "imgur", "facebook", "google", "ionbank", "paypal", "aol", "amazon", "reddit"];

    var adder = (function () {
    var arraynum = 0;
    return function() {return arraynum += 1} })();

    function linkSwitch() {
        x = adder();
        x;
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
            document.getElementById("youtube").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 1:
            document.getElementById("imgur").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 2:
            document.getElementById("facebook").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 3:
            document.getElementById("google").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 4:
            document.getElementById("ionbank").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 5:
            document.getElementById("paypal").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 6:
            document.getElementById("aol").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 7:
            document.getElementById("amazon").style.display = block;
            break;
            case 8:
            document.getElementById("reddit").style.display = block;
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This was supposed to have a counter count up by one when the button was clicked, every time the counter went up by one, the linkSwitch() function was supposed to check which id to use, so if the counter was on 4, it would display the ionbank image & link.

When that didn't work, I thought that changing the id would result in a cleaner/space efficient code that worked, however, it still doesn't work:

```
<body>
<div id="backnext">
    <button class="button2" id="back"> < </button>
    <button class="button2" id="next" onclick="linkSwitch()"> > </button>
    <div id="tablecontainer">
        <ul id="tablelinks">
            <li> <!--Youtube Link-->
                <a id="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Imgur Link-->
                <a id="imgur" href="https://imgur.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Facebook Link-->
                <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Google Link-->
                <a id="google" href="https://www.google.com/"> </a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Ion Bank Link-->
                <a id="ionbank" href="https://ionbank.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Paypal Link-->
                <a id="paypal" href="https://www.paypal.com/home"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Aol Link-->
                <a id="aol" href="https://mail.aol.com/webmail-std/en-us/suite"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Amazon Link-->
                <a id="amazon" href="http://www.amazon.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <!--Reddit Link-->
                <a id="reddit" href="https://www.reddit.com/"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div>

<script>
var id, arraynum, x;
id = ["youtube", "imgur", "facebook", "google", "ionbank", "paypal", "aol", "amazon", "reddit"];

    var adder = (function () {
        var arraynum = 0;
        return function() {return arraynum += 1} })();

    function linkSwitch() {
        x = id[adder() % 9];
        return document.getElementById(x).style.display = block;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions on where this might've went wrong would be greatly appreciated, here's the full code (1 HTML and 1 CSS file) https://gist.github.com/sabs21/ce49655253eab2802beca76c8306a132

Comment: `return document.getElementById(x).style.display = block;` should be `return document.getElementById(x).style.display = 'block';` (you forgot to put "block" in quotes so it's interpreted as a string literal, not a variable)

Comment: Thank you!! I'm not sure how to upvote this answer, but this did the trick!